# nombre de boton

Tags: php

tengo un sitio que estoy realizando en PHP, solo que tengo una duda.

tengo unos ciclos while y agregan botones solo que en el boton tengo

```html
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$id = $row["ID"];
$Auditor = $row["Auditor"];
$auditoria = $row["Auditoria"];
$Fdeseada = $row["Fdeseada"];
$Flimite = $row["Flimite"];
 echo "<tr>
     <td align='right' class='estilo1'> $id </td>
     <td class='estilo1'> $Auditor </td>
     <td class='estilo1'> $auditoria </td>
     <td class='estilo1'> $Fdeseada </td>
     <td class='estilo1'> $Flimite </td>
         <td class='estilo1'> $row[Estado] </td>
             <td class='estilo1'><A HREF='verEncuesta.php'> Realizar </A></td>
             <td><input type='submit' name='borrar' class='submit' value =".$id."></td>                    
  </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

que me manda el id a otro archivo php que me realiza el borrado de la linea solo que en mi boton aparece borrado + el numero de ID y yo solo quiero que diga Borrar pero si le pongo Borrar no me elimina por que no paso el ID. como puedo mejorar esta parte.

archivo eliminar

```html
if ($_POST["borrar"]) {
    $id = $_POST["borrar"];
    $query = "Delete From tareas Where ID='$id'";
 if ($conexion->query($query) === TRUE) {
 echo "<br />" . "<h2>" . "Tarea eliminada Exitosamente!" . "</h2>";
 echo "<h5>" . "<a href='calendario.php'>Regresar</a>" . "</h5>"; 
 }
 else {
 echo "Error al crear el empreado." . $query . "<br>" . $conexion->error; 
   }
    
}
```

Comment: Pon tu codigo completo incluyendo el ciclo para ver que valor va tomando tu variable **$id**

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco mejor el contexto, por favor?

Comment: tengo un boton y quiero que me aparezca Borrar en el boton pero me aparece el numero ID, se que es por el value pero si quito el value ya no me manda el valor al otro archivo eliminar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar un input tipo hidden, para que te muestre el campo oculto, y en tu archivo de eliminar obtener ese nuevo valor $id = $_POST["prodId"];

```html
<input id="prodId" name="prodId" type="hidden" value='".$id."'>

En tus botones:
<td class='estilo1'> $row[Estado] </td>
         <td class='estilo1'><A HREF='verEncuesta.php'> Realizar </A></td>
         <td>
<input id="prodId" name="prodId" type="hidden" value='".$id."'>
<input type='submit' name='borrar' class='submit' value ="borrar">
</td>
```

Comment: Si lo ponés así está mal, primero por las comillas simples y dobles, al omitir la comilla simple dentro del value, no va a funcionar y segundo porque el nombre del botón va a tener de nombre el `id` y él pide que diga "borrar". Además deberías aclarar que debería cambiar el nombre del borrado en el archivo de eliminar.

Answer (score 1):

Me imagino que está todo dentro de un `<form method="post" action="eliminar.php"></form>` o algo parecido, suponiendo eso, lo que deberías hacer es agregarle un `<input type="hidden" />` con el nombre y valor que quieras para eliminar.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $id = $row["ID"];
  $Auditor = $row["Auditor"];
  $auditoria = $row["Auditoria"];
  $Fdeseada = $row["Fdeseada"];
  $Flimite = $row["Flimite"];
  echo "<tr>
     <td align='right' class='estilo1'> $id </td>
     <td class='estilo1'> $Auditor </td>
     <td class='estilo1'> $auditoria </td>
     <td class='estilo1'> $Fdeseada </td>
     <td class='estilo1'> $Flimite </td>
     <td class='estilo1'> $row[Estado] </td>
     <td class='estilo1'><A HREF='verEncuesta.php'> Realizar </A></td>
     <td>
       <input type='hidden' name='borrar' value='".$id."' />
       <input type='submit' class='submit' value='borrar' />
     </td>                    
  </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Luego en el archivo de **eliminar.php** debería estar eso que pasaste para que elimine el registro.